# Is there a difference between ĉagreni & ĝeni

Tags: word-meaning, meaning-in-context

From what I understand, they both basically mean to annoy, but is there a difference or is it just up to the speaker? Are there any situations where one is more appropriate than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *ĝeni* is a bit more general and doesn’t necessarily imply an emotional reaction. Maybe it is closer to *bother* or *hinder* in English. You could say:

> La malbone parkita aŭto ĝenas la rubkolektadon.

The badly parked car causes trouble for the rubbish collection, but it doesn’t necessarily make the refuse collectors angry.

For comparison:

> Ĉagrenas min ke iu ŝtelis mian biciklon.

There it is describing an emotional reaction to the problem. The bike theft made them angry.

Comment: So basically "to annoy" vs "to anger"?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Personally I would say that _annoy_ also implies an emotional reaction, but just less so than “[make] angry”. Whereas the object of _ĝeni_ doesn’t even have to be a human, like in the example.